# Breaking a loop from another thread

Tags: c++, qt, loops, break, qthread

Currently I have two classes that look something like this:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    bool aborted = false;

public:
    Worker() : QObject() {}

public slots:
    void abort() { aborted = true; }

    void doWork()
    {
        while(!aborted && !work_finished)
        {
            //do work
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() : QObject()
    {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::startWork, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(this, &Controller::aborted, worker, &Worker::abort);
    }

signals:
    void startWork();
    void aborted();
};

Controller *cont = new Controller;
emit cont->startWork(); // Start the loop
emit cont->aborted(); // Stop the loop
```

So the idea is that there is a loop running in a `Worker` thread, which can be stopped from a `Controller` thread.

In the example this is done by calling `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`, which allows signals to call slots before returning control to the loop.
It's important the loop is only stopped at the start or end of an iteration.

Although this works nicely, I think `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` is pretty expensive, at least when used inside a very long loop (up to thousands in practice).

**So my question is, how can I achieve the same result in a better/cheaper way?**

Comment: You could use an atomic variable to communicate that information. Or just use [`QThread::isInterruptionRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested) together with [`QThread::requestInterruption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three alternative solutions that I'm aware of at this time.

### 1. [`QThread::requestInterruption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption) (suggested by @Felix)

According to [`QThread::isInterruptionRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested):

> Take care not to call it too often, to keep the overhead low.

Whereas [`QCoreApplication::processEvents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) makes no remark on performance or memory usage, so I don't think `QThread::requestInterruption` is an improvement over `QCoreApplication::processEvents` in this case.

---

### 2. [`std::atomic`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/) (suggested by @Felix)

> The main characteristic of atomic objects is that access to this contained value from different threads cannot cause data races [...]

The boolean can be stored inside a `std::atomic` which can be made a member of the `Controller` class instead of the `Worker` class. Then we need to pass a reference to `aborted` to and store it in `Worker`, and set it to `true` from `Controller` when needed.

I didn't fully test this approach, so please correct me if I got something wrong.

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    std::atomic<bool> &aborted;
public:
    Worker(std::atomic<bool> &aborted) : QObject(), aborted(aborted) {}
public slots:
    void doWork() {
        while(!aborted.load() && !work_finished) /* do work */
    }
};

class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
    std::atomic<bool> aborted;
public:
    Controller() : QObject() {
        aborted.store(false);
        Worker *worker = new Worker(aborted);
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::startWork, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(this, &Controller::aborted, worker, &Worker::abort);
    }

    void abort() { aborted.store(true); }
signals:
    void startWork();
};

Controller *cont = new Controller;
emit cont->startWork(); // Start the loop
cont->abort(); // Stop the loop
```

---

### 3. [`QWaitCondition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html) & [`QMutex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html)

A boolean `paused` will be needed. `Controller` and `Worker` need read/write access to it.

Set `paused` to `true` in `Controller` when needed.
During the loop in `Worker`, `if(paused)`: [`QWaitCondition::wait()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html#wait) until [`QWaitCondition::wakeAll()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html#wakeAll) is called from the calling thread.
[`QMutex::lock`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#lock) will need to be called whenever `paused` is accessed.

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    bool &aborted, &paused;
    QWaitCondition &waitCond;
    QMutex &mutex;
public:
    Worker(bool &aborted, bool &paused, QWaitCondition &waitCond, QQMutex &mutex)
        : QObject(), aborted(aborted), paused(paused), waitCond(waitCond), mutex(mutex) {}
public slots:
    void doWork() {
        while(!aborted && !work_finished) {
            //do work
            mutex.lock();
            if(paused) {
                waitCond.wait(&mutex);
                paused = false;
            }
            mutex.unlock();
        }
    }

    void abort() { aborted = true; }
};

class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    bool aborted=false, paused=false;
    QWaitCondition waitCond;
    QMutex mutex;
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() : QObject() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker(aborted, paused, waitCond, mutex);
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::startWork, worker, &Worker::doWork);
    }
    void abort() {
        mutex.lock();
        paused = true; // Worker starts waiting
        mutex.unlock();

        if(confirmed_by_user) aborted = true; // Don't need to lock because Worker is waiting
        waitCond.wakeAll(); // Worker resumes loop
    }
signals:
    void startWork();
};

Controller *cont = new Controller();
emit cont->startWork(); // Start the loop
cont->abort(); // Stop the loop
```